# JQ : Parse specific output (get IP) from JSON file

Tags: json, shell, ubuntu, jq

I want to get the IPs that has 'server.sh' value. My current script gets all the IPs

**test.json**

```
{
  "nodes": {
    "test1.local": {
      ":ip": "192.168.56.30",
      ":server": "server.sh",
      ":client": "client.sh"
    },
    "test2.local": {
      ":ip": "192.168.56.31",
      ":server": "server.sh",
      ":client": "client.sh"
    },
    "test3.local": {
      ":ip": "192.168.56.32",
      ":client": "client.sh"
    }
  }
}
```

**test.sh**

```
ips=`jq -c '.nodes | to_entries | map(.value.":ip")| map_values(.+":4648")' test.json`
echo $ips
```

`["192.168.56.30:4648","192.168.56.31:4648","192.168.56.32:4648"]`

Comment: Note that `echo $ips` is innately buggy. *Always* quote your expansions: `echo "$ips"`; see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), and the Stack Overflow question [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else).

Comment: ...and it's strongly preferred to use `ips=$(jq ...)` instead of legacy backtick command-substitution syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Is it ok for your task?

```
jq '.nodes|.[]|select(.":server"=="server.sh")|.":ip"+":4648"' test.json 
"192.168.56.30:4648"
"192.168.56.31:4648"
```

Comment: yup. i need it on this format
["192.168.56.30:4648","192.168.56.31:4648"]

Comment: Then make it `jq -cn '[inputs|.nodes[]|select(.":server"=="server.sh")|"\(.":ip"):4648"]'`